# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value swift error

Tags: xcode, swift

I am writing a simple program that shows and takes away images and I keep getting the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func BeginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.Retry.hidden = false
    self.Begin.hidden = true
    self.Logo.hidden = true
    self.GameOver.hidden = false
    self.ScoreBoard.hidden = false
}

@IBAction func RetryButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.Begin.hidden = false
    self.Retry.hidden = true
    self.Logo.hidden = false
    self.GameOver.hidden = true
    self.ScoreBoard.hidden = true
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: Where exactly is the error taking place?

Comment: Are all your IBOutlets connected properly

Comment: change sender: UIButton, then try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect your IBOutlets (self.Retry, self.Begin, ...) with the corresponding views in Interface Builder. Right now, one or more of them are `nil`.

Here's a detailed explanation from Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html